# Why calculating distance between two lat,long gives wrong result?

Tags: java, android

I have taken this code from Stackoverflow and it was marked as working. I am just testing it but in my case it gives wrong result. the actual distance is about 139 km b/w these points but it show 2.07.. km. Method return distance in meter as mentioned then i convert it into km but it gives me wrong value. please help.[image]

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot. Do you expect us to type everything?

Comment: I will be careful next time. Got the solution. Thanks

Comment: @YousafIqbal, please still [edit] your question and insert the code. Remember that you're not just asking for yourself, but for everyone else who finds this question/answer in search results. Code in an image never shows up in Google. Taking the time to post your code in the answer is part of being a responsible member of StackOverflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550674/android-calculate-distance-between-two-locations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu) link, you will definitely find needed result.

I used this formula, it worked:

```
        double R = 6371.0; // km
        double dLat = (lat2-lat1)*Math.PI/180.0;
        double dLon = (lon2-lon1)*Math.PI/180.0;
        lat1 = lat1*Math.PI/180.0;
        lat2 = lat2*Math.PI/180.0;

        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2.0) * Math.sin(dLat/2.0) +
                Math.sin(dLon/2.0) * Math.sin(dLon/2.0) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        double d = R * c;       

        return d*1000;
```

Comment: Yes it is giving me about 143 which is fine.

Comment: It is also returning distance in meters right?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll need to do is figure out the coordinate system and projection system that you're using to calculate the distance. Could you provide the coordinates that you're using?

If you're using [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System), the answer above will work. Otherwise, you'll need to re-project the points in the current coordinate system.